# How to use clipboard-cli on Wayland?

Tags: shell-script, clipboard, stdin, vlc

I am using this module `gtts-cli` for text to speech conversion.

more info here-> https://gtts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html

Basic syntax is

```bsh
$ gtts-cli 'hello' --output /tmp/hello.mp3 && vlc --play-and-exit /tmp/hello.mp3 && rm /tmp/hello.mp3
```

I want to write a bash script where the highlighted text (from firefox for example) is sent as a variable to the text portion (in quotes) in the above syntax. I'm on Wayland so I can't use `xsel`. Then, after VLC finishes playing the mp3 file, I would like vlc to autoclose itself and finally delete the generated mp3 file. Ultimately, I would like to bind the script to a keyboard shortcut. Highlight some text on the screen, then run the script using the shortcut.

Is there an easier way to achieve this? `gtts-cli 'hello'` outputs a bunch of random characters. Is it possible to pipe the `stdout`of `gtts-cli 'hello'` as `stdin` to VLC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `wayland` you can use [wl-clipboard](https://github.com/bugaevc/wl-clipboard) as a clipboard, then you can use an input event like [sxhkd](https://github.com/baskerville/sxhkd) in `X` ,  for `wayland`  [Hawck](https://github.com/snyball/Hawck), [evscript](https://github.com/myfreeweb/evscript) and [evdevremapkeys](https://github.com/philipl/evdevremapkeys)...

Comment: can you help me with the basic syntax of assigning a variable to the clipboard content on wl-clipboard? `wl-copy > $x && gtts-cli '$x'` something like that? I have no idea where to start.

Comment: use double quotes:    `gtts-cli "$(wl-paste)" --output /tmp/hello.mp3 && vlc --play-and-exit /tmp/hello.mp3 && rm /tmp/hello.mp3`

Comment: The above command would require me to copy the text first(using ctrl+c) then run the script.
Is there a way to run the `wl-copy` command on the selected text first then chain it with `&&` the above command?I tried to assign `wl-copy` to a shortcut, then highlight a text, then pressed the shortcut. I was not able to copy the selected text onto the clipboard.

Comment: are you meen, ifyou use `ctrl+c` then you use wl-past , the output is different to text selected

Comment: first highlighting the text then `ctrl+c`. This successfully puts the text into the clipboard. `wl-paste` shows correctly. but how to I simulate a `ctrl+c` press into the bash script? I don't want to highlight text, then press `ctrl+c` ,and then run the script. I want to simply highlight text, and then run script. Is it possible?

Comment: Actually, I was wrong about `xsel`. It DOES work in wayland. Everything works as I want it to now. thanks

Comment: `<ctrll+c>` ==> en terminal `echo "text" | wl-copy` or `wl-copy "Hello world!"` or `wl-copy < ~/Pictures/photo.png`

Comment: so it's easy with piple like `./app.sh | wl-copy `

Comment: those are really helpful syntax to know. thanks again!